# Send large data to mobile device over web service

Tags: web-services, mobile

I was asked this question durning an interview: How to send large data to a phone?

I've heard words like "long pulling" or "streaming" but I don't know how to do it. Finally I said you can split the data to smaller chunks and send it over HTTP. The interviewer said "Well that was interesting...". I guess that was not a good sign.:(

Anyway, what is the best practice for sending large data file to a mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following approach in recent project:

1. Mobile device requests data from server via web service and starts to send requests with time interval to check if server is ready with data
2. Server prepares large response, packs it to ZIP file (compression is pretty good for text files with raw data - 5MB goes to 100Kb) and places this file to a specified folder
3. Mobile device gets a response from server that data is ready. This response contains a link to file.
4. Mobile device downloads the file, unpacks it - you got your data on mobile!

The same approach is used to send data from mobile to server.